# Why do I have to spread a Vuex getter from one module and not one from another module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I have a VueX store with two modules, user.js and merchant.js, top level is index.js.

The getter in user.js is:

**Refactor**

```
  const getters = {
  selectedShippingAddress (state) {
    return state
      .shippingAddresses.find(({ shippingAddressId }) => shippingAddressId 
      === state.selectedShippingAddressId)
     }
    }
```

**Old Version**

```
   selectedShippingAddress (state) {
    return state
      .shippingAddresses
      .filter(({ shippingAddressId }) => shippingAddressId === state.selectedShippingAddressId)
      .pop()
  }
```

The getter in merchant.js is

```
    merchantAllowedShippingCountries (state) {
      if (state.shippingLocationProfiles) {
        return state.shippingLocationProfiles.split(',')
       } else {
         return []
        }
      }
     }
```

Lastly the index.js:

```
   isCountrySupportedByMerchant (state, getters) {

    **// the const userShippingAddress fails **
    const userShippingAddress = getters.selectedShippingAddress

    **// this works with spreading **
    const userShippingAddress = { ...getters.selectedShippingAddress }
    const countriesMerchantShipsTo = getters.countriesAllowedForShipping
    for (const country in countriesMerchantShipsTo) {
      if (userShippingAddress.countryCode === country) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }
```

I'm asking this question because the app fails as well as an integration test when not using the spread operator.

Both versions of the user.js, the refactor using find, and the old one using pop(), both return undefined if the array is empty. I suspect that this has to do with the fact that find() uses a callback and pop() doesn't. Or is this about property access because I need to get countryCode in the loop?

Why does this work only when I spread the getter from user.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const userShippingAddress = getters.selectedShippingAddress
```

when then array is empty, then `userShippingAddress` will be `undefined`,so `userShippingAddress.countryCode` will cause an error.

However when you spread the getter from user.js `{ ...getters.selectedShippingAddress }` will be an Object, like this `{}`, so the `userShippingAddress.countryCode` will work fine.

Comment: As I was waiting for an answer, I suspected it was about property access. Appreciate the clarification.